# MongoDb import a json file into already existing collection as an update to single entry

Tags: json, mongodb, shell, mongoimport

I have a mongo collection that looks like this:

```
{   "identifier" : "BM10003",
    "count" : "0",
    "data" :{
           "label1":"value1",
           "label2":"value2",
     }
}
```

In the above collection identifier field is unique and I use that to add more data to this entry. Now i want to import a json file that gets added to this collection under the key `data2`. Is there a simple shell command to do a mongoimport by looking for a identifier and just appending the jsonarray to this entry?

Comment: Not sure I understand it completely. For matching on identifier other than _id you can use --upsertFields option. So something like `mongoimport -c colname -d database --mode merge --upsertFields identifier --file filename.json` ( not tested )

Comment: Yeah thats not going to work. json file doesnot have _id parameter to allow the merge. I am looking for a command where I can upsert after matching identifier to BM10003 and insert json file. I am assuming there is no way to do this in shell. Currently I am using python to insert this json
result = db.external.update_one({'identifier': 'BM10003'},
                       {'$set': {'data2': json_file}}, upsert=True)

Comment: Doint it in python is just adding another step of readin the json file into a json object in python and then updating record in mongodb. Was wondering if there is any way of doing this using shell which would avoid reading the file